# How to get parent id in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi please check my code:

```
<table>
<tr id="record-1">
    <td>22-Sep-2014</td>
    <td>jyoti</td>
    <td>Testing Subject</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
        <div align="center" style="margin:auto;">
        <a class="delete-icon" onclick=" return deleteMessage(this);" href="javascript:;">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get the `tr` id `record-1`

Jquery:

```
function deleteMessage(this_record){
    var id = $(this_record).parent('tr').id;
    //var id = $(this_record).parent('tr').attr('id');
    alert(id);
}
```

Above jquery code i am getting `undefined` alert. How to get `record-1`?

Comment: var id = $(this_record).parent().parent().attr('id');

Comment: Hello @Mysteryos this is not duplicate. Please check your duplicate link. This opposite answer of my question.

Comment: @Mysteryos i was seeing this link before you posted here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) with [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
function deleteMessage(this_record){
    var id = $(this_record).closest('tr').attr('id');
    alert(id);
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jusxx1r2/)

Comment: yes `closest` that is the nice answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) with [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) as shown below :

```
function deleteMessage(this_record){
    var id = $(this_record).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
    alert(id);
}
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/upm7zvsb/3/)

OR

```
function deleteMessage(this_record){
    var id = $(this_record).parents().find('tr').attr('id');
    alert(id);
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upm7zvsb/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Using your jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('a.delete-icon').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

Then you can remove the `onclick` property of the link.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/oqs32ttt/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get `parent id` in `JQuery` by using [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) methods.

```
function deleteMessage(this_record)
{
    var id = $(this_record).closest('tr').attr('id');
    alert(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(‘tr’).parents().find(‘#record-t’);
```

I believe this works, sorry I will test shortly, because your "parents()" are able to be search by find() in jQuery using the "ID" '#record-t'.

I know funny nerd puns but, thats the easiest way I know in jQuery. ***Hope this helps, Sean.***

Comment: my `record-n` coming dynamic it may be `record-1` or `record-nth` i got my answer. `closest` is the best answer for me. Thanks for tried. :)